# Get an array of class static member variables

Tags: php

Example class:

```
class Example{
   public static $ONE = [1,'one'];
   public static $TWO = [2,'two'];
   public static $THREE = [3,'three'];

   public static function test(){

       // manually created array 
       $arr = [
           self::$ONE,
           self::$TWO,
           self::$THREE
       ];
   }       
}
```

Is there a way in PHP to get an array of class static member variables without creating it manually like in the example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there is:

Using [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php), and the [getStaticProperties()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getstaticproperties.php) method

```
class Example{
   public static $ONE = [1,'one'];
   public static $TWO = [2,'two'];
   public static $THREE = [3,'three'];

   public static function test(){
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class()); 
        return $reflection->getStaticProperties();
    }       
}

var_dump(Example::test());
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/U0dYs)